# Admin tool to manage hyperledger fabric blockchain network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

When I install a hyperledger fabric network (as instructed on hyperledger.readthedocs.io), it gives me ability to communicate with the deployed blockchain instance. There are a few CLI commands that I can use to stop/restart the service.

I am looking for a UI based tool, that an admin user can leverage to view the activity, as well as control the different entities in the blockchain network.

Note: I have already seen Blockchain explorer but its apparently a read-only tool.

Many Thanks.

Comment: For me Explorer in its 1.0 version is totally useless and buggy. I have personnaly built an admin control panel directly in my application using the Java SDK and it's actually not that difficult, in a single day I had about the same features as Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think **Hyperledger Composer** is best way to access the Hyperledger Fabric Network.

It Provides UI to access full blockchain network.

You can find the tutorials [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/introduction/introduction).

Also, if you want to view total blocks, transactions, peers data, then You can use **Hyperledger Blockchain Explorer**.

The link is [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer).

Comment: Hyperledger composer is deprecated now. So it's not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Cello is the tool which can help you to manage blockchain in an efficient way.

Using Cello, everyone can easily:

Build up a Blockchain as a Service (BaaS) platform quickly from scratch.
Provision customizable Blockchains instantly, e.g., a Hyperledger fabric network v1.0.
Maintain a pool of running blockchain networks on top of baremetals, Virtual Clouds (e.g., virtual machines, vsphere Clouds), Container clusters (e.g., Docker, Swarm, Kubernetes).
Check the system status, adjust the chain numbers, scale resources... through dashboards.

https://cello.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
[enter link description here](https://github.com/hyperledger/cello)

Comment: I tried it back in Aug. It was not ready for use back then. Basically installed it completely but was not able to create chains.

Answer (score 0):

I think IBM blockchain framework is the best to manage the hyperledger fabric network. It's providing UI web console for network management.